# Don't understand cause of this TypeError with method get_time()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I'd like to use method `get_date()` on widget `DateEntry`. I just want to get this date to do expiry remainder. But ir raises an error: `TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date`. How to get rid of this error?

Part of code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar,DateEntry
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
root = Tk()
root.title("Medicine database")

curr_date = datetime.now()
time_diff = timedelta(days=30)
reqdate = curr_date + time_diff

def add_medicine():
    tree.insert("",END,values=(e0.get(),e1.get(),e2.get(),cal1.get()))
    e0.delete(0,END)
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e2.delete(0,END)

    #here I used method get_date()

    expiry_date = cal1.get_date()
    if reqdate == expiry_date:
        print("The product has expired")

#etykiety
lb0 = Label(root,text="Serial number")
lb0.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=1,columnspan=1)
lb1 = Label(root,text="Medicine name")
lb1.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,columnspan=1)
lb2 = Label(root,text="Quantity")
lb2.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=3,columnspan=1)
lb3 = Label(root,text="Expiry date")
lb3.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=2,columnspan=1)
#okienka
e0 = Entry(root,width=15)
e0.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=1,sticky=W) 
e1 = Entry(root,width=15)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=W)
e2 = Entry(root,width=15)
e2.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=3,sticky=W)
cal1 = DateEntry(root,width=12,bg="darkblue",fg="white",date_pattern="dd/mm/yyyy",year=2020,state="readonly")
cal1.grid(row=1,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=W)
#klawisze
btn1 = Button(root,text="Add new\nmedicine",width=10,command=add_medicine)
btn1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=15,rowspan=3)

#treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=25)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three","four")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=160)
tree.column("three",width=130)
tree.column("four",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Serial number")
tree.heading("two", text="Medicine name")
tree.heading("three", text="Quantity")
tree.heading("four",text="Expiry date")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=0,column=2,rowspan=6,pady=20)
scbr2= Scrollbar(root,orient="vertical",command=tree.yview)
scbr2.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=W,columnspan=1,rowspan=6,padx=1,ipady=240)
tree.config(yscrollcommand=scbr2.set)
scbr3= Scrollbar(root,orient="horizontal",command=tree.xview)
scbr3.grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=S,ipadx=260)
tree.config(xscrollcommand=scbr3.set)

root.geometry("840x580")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because the `get_date()` method returns a `datetime.date` instance, however the `reqdate` value your code is calculating is a `datetime.datetime`.

You should be able to avoid the problem by making `reqdate` the same type that is being returned by the method with something along these lines:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
...

#curr_date = datetime.now()
curr_date = date.today()
time_diff = timedelta(days=30)
reqdate = curr_date + time_diff
...
```

Comment: Ok it worked but I've got no idea how to write the code that it highlights rows of the expired medicine. I've wrote for eg.  expiry_date = cal1.get_date()
if reqdate <= cal1:
    print("Yeah")
else:
    print("No")

Comment: Can you give me advice how to do it properlly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familar with tkcalendar and besides, you're asking about something completely tangential to the subject of this question — so I suggest you post a new one on this other topic. By sure to include the relevant code you have.

Comment: I forgot to add that I meant this and it worked but sth its wrong I have reached my limit for questions:                                                                       
   expiry_date = cal1.get_date()
    selections = []
    for child in tree.get_children():
        if reqdate > expiry_date:
            selections.append(child)
            print("30 days left")
        elif reqdate < expiry_date:
            selections.append(child)
            print("Product date has expired")
        else:
            pass
        tree.selection_set(selections)